# How do I make a program that asks the user for a limit and

Tags: python-3.x, numbers, square-root

I've got this code that asks the user for a limit, and then prints out the sequence of square numbers that are less than or equal to the limit provided.

```
n=int(input("Limit: "))
counter = 2
while counter <= n:
    a = counter*counter
    counter=a
    print(a)
```

This is my current code, it's meant to work like this:

```
Max: 100
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
100
```

I'm stuck, how do I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you will want to start your `counter` variable at 1, otherwise you won't be able to get '1' as a square value.

In terms of printing the rest of the values, you will need to do 3 things:

1. Check if the square of counter is less than the limit.
2. If it is than the limit, print the result of counter * counter.
3. Increment counter by 1 **<-- This is important!**

Incrementing the counter by 1, is going to allow you to check every possible square that could exist below the specified limit. The following code provides a simple way to accomplish this that matches the pseudocode above:

```
n=int(input("Limit: "))
counter = 1
while counter <= n:
    if counter * counter <= n:
        print(counter * counter)
    counter += 1
```

Let me know if you have any questions, I'm happy to clarify anything that still isn't making sense!

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually calculating successive squares.  You should be finding the square of `counter`, and then increasing `counter` by one

```
n=int(input("Limit: "))
counter = 1
sq = counter**2
while sq <= n:
    print(sq)
    counter += 1
    sq = counter**2
```

Fun itertools solution:

```
from itertools import accumulate, count, takewhile

for i in takewhile(n.__gt__, accumulate(count(1, 2))):
    print(i)
```